# Android FFMPEG - Loading a http radio url and decoding to play it

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, decode, aac

I'm trying to load a aac radio stream and play it. For this I'm trying to decode the audio and play it using audiotrack.

I'm trying to use FFMPEG for this purpose. Is it possible to pass in the http url and ask ffmpeg's method av_open_input_file to open the http url? I'm trying to do this but its showing some errors while I'm compiling it.

Has anyone tried this. Is this possible?

Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 1):

I have tested some apps on my droid. See the code for these apps here.

http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/

https://github.com/havlenapetr/android_packages_apps_FMRadio

Which works perfectly well on my droid. Hope this helps.